# Does webpack support split file?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-loader

I would like to develop a loader or a plugin that support split some function from origin file.
For example, I have a file 'index.js'

```
// index.js
function a() {
  console.log('111');
}

function b() {
  console.log('222');
}

function c() {
  if (xx) {
    a();
  } else {
    b();
  }
}
c();
```

I will split then into two chunks, and lazy import then

```
// chunk a.js
export function a() {
  console.log('111');
}
```

// chunk b.js

```
export function b() {
  console.log('222');
}
```

// index.js

```
function c() {
  if (xx) {
    import('./a.js').then((mod) => mod.a());
  } else {
    import('./b.js').then((mod) => mod.b());
  }
}
c();
```

I use compilation emitAsset to generate a.js and b.js, and modify index.js in a custom loader
But will failed when build.
It throw error 'can not find module './a.js'',
How can I do to support this feature?
Is there a good way that no need to change the origin source code?

File should be split in new chunks. And can be imported successfully in origin file.